# Are these sets H and K compact?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have to state if these sets are compact:

$H = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^8 + y^8 - x^4 + y^4 \le 1\}$

$K = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:-1 \le x^3 + xy + y^3 \le 1\}$

For sure both K is closed, because 
$K = K_1 \cap K_2$ with $K_1 = \{x^3 + xy + y^3 \le 1\} = f^{-1}((-\infty, 1])$ and $K_2 = \{x^3 + xy + y^3 \ge -1\} = g^{-1}([-1, +\infty))$.
H is also closed, I know because I've plotted it, but I can't prove it (help). 
Then I have to find if H and K are bounded... I think K is not bounded and H is bounded for sure, but again i can't prove it.
Can you help me? Thanks in advice

Comment: You got it wrong.  The set $H$ is not bounded, while $K$ is.  Try to write $x^8+y^8-x^4+y^4$ as a sum of squares (plus a constant).  Also, show that for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $x^3+xy+y^3=0$.

Comment: For the closure of $H$: how about $f(x,y) = x^8 + y^8 - x^4 + y^4$, and $K = f^{-1}((-\infty,1])$.

Comment: The approach is good (compact $\iff$ closed and bound in the plane) but as Batominovski points out, the claims of boundedness need correction.

Comment: while writing the sets I inverted K and H, I'm sorry.

Comment: I got it... as Batominovski suggested, we can write $x^8 + y^8 - x^4 + y^4$ as a sum of squares plus a constant: $(x^4 - 1/2)^2 + (y^4 + 1/2)^2 - 1/2$. So we can say that $0 < x^8+y^8−x^4+y^4 \le 3/2$ : this prove that H is bounded. Now I have to prove that K is not bounded...